# Dask: Continue with others task if one fails

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I have a simple (but large) task Graph in Dask. This is a code example

```
results = []

for params in SomeIterable:
    a = dask.delayed(my_function)(**params)
    b = dask.delayed(my_other_function)(a)
    results.append(b)

dask.compute(**results)
```

Here `SomeIterable` is a list of `dict`, where each are arguments to `my_function`. In each iteration `b` depends on `a`, so if the task that produces `a` fails, `b` can't be computed. But, each element of `results` are independent, so I expect if one fails, the other can continue running. This does not happen in practice, if an element of `results` fails, then the execution of the script ends.

EDIT:

This **also** happen when using the `submit` (or `map`) method of the client class `dask.distributed.Client`, for example

```
futures = [client.submit(my_other_function_2, **params) for params in MyOtherIterable]
results = [ft.result() for ft in futures]
```

In the code above if one task fails when I try to gather a result, all code fails as in the [docs](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/resilience.html)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you do not want to use the `client.submit` API? (AFAIK they are equivalent under the hood)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way out of this is to wrap your functions in `try/except`, so something like this:

```py
def try_f(params):
    try:
        a = my_function(**params)
        b = my_other_function(a)
    except:
        b = f"Failed for: {params}"
    return b

results = [dask.delayed(try_f)(params) for params in SomeIterable]
computed = dask.compute(results)
```

However, depending on your case, you might want to use the `client.submit` API, since it will give you some further flexibility, e.g. specifying some conditional retries.

Comment: Thanks, in the end that's what I did haha

Comment: If that works for you @Andrex, you should accept it :-)